# PHPStorm Namespace support not working for Symfony2 projects

Tags: php, ide, namespaces, phpstorm

I'm evaluating PHPStorm right now, and I've really grown fond of it. It's fast, has more or less everything perfectly implemented and the flow flows like a breeze...

The only thing bugging me (and that's a big one) is, that it doesn't seem to get the namespaces for my symfony2 project right.

See, in Netbeans, when I type `use Symf[CTRL+SPACE]` it show me all the Symfony namespaces, right out of the `/vendors` folder.

If I do the same in PHPStorm, no namesapces are shown. That means that the whole code copletion doesn't work for the vendor libraries, which is really very, very bad in terms of easy and fast programming.

Now, I'm quite sure that I'm just missing a setting somewhere, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a [known issue in PhpStorm](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-6149).

Answer (score 6):

The Question is a bit old, but if anyone stumbles across it (like me) and still nothing works, it might be because your vendor folder gets excluded from code inspection.

You have to go to "File -> Settings -> Directories" and set the vendor folder to be a resource root and not be excluded.

More info here: [Jetbrains Namespaces](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHP+Namespaces+and+PSR+Support+in+PhpStorm#PHPNamespacesandPSRSupportinPhpStorm-PSR-4support)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue anymore, there is a [Symfony](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm) plugin that works most of the time now.