# Git ignore inline docblock

Tags: php, git, namespaces, phpstorm, docblocks

When using factory-like patterns, PhpStorm only recognises classes when docblock comment is used. Example:

```
/** @var \Some\Thing $thing */
$thing = $this->factory('some/thing');
$thing->doSomething();
```

Without the `@var` declaration, PhpStorm doesn't know `doSomething()` is a method of the `\Some\Thing` class. If it were entirely up to me, I would just add these docblock comments. However, my coworkers dislike inline docblock comments.

Is there a way to either:

- Ignore these docblocks when committing (eg filter by regex) or
- Teach phpstorm how to find the class name based on the 'some/thing' argument or
- Use another method to keep these comments only in my own working copy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPStorm Namespace support not working for Symfony2 projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172312/phpstorm-namespace-support-not-working-for-symfony2-projects)

Comment: It seems it's a known issue about phpstorm and namespacing. The following video may help you : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVvBKDB1NNQ

Comment: This is a very subjective question (and it doesn't answer the question as you state it), so I'm just going to post this as a comment: Option 4; Continue using them en make your coworkers provide valid reasons against them, because "I don't like them" is not a valid reason. Add a text description in addition to the `@` tags and they'll have even less of a leg to stand on.

Comment: You can try **DynamicReturnType Plugin** -- may help here. PhpStorm does not currently support such factory methods for **ordinary classes/methods** (see [WI-18075](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18075)) -- ATM it only supports [static methods](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-6027) or [global functions](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20096).